# XPath: Find element that contains exact text while doing translate and normalize-space

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, xpath

I am unsure about the correct XPath syntax to achieve these objectives:

- The text content of the element on the web page should be ***exactly*** `"ABC"`, except:
- I want to use `translate` so that I can search with `"abc"` and find `"ABC"`
- I want to do `normalize-space`

I know the syntax for `translate` and `normalize-text` when using `contains`, namely:

```
"//*[contains(translate(normalize-space(.), '%s), '%s')]" % ("ABC', 'abc'", "abc")
 #                                                           ↑ Translation   ↑ Target
```

This will find an element that *contains* `"ABC"` like `"ABCD"` when searching with `"abc"`.

But, I am struggling with the correct syntax when not using `contains`, i.e. that the text content has to be *exactly* `"ABC"` and not `"ABCD"` and be found with `"abc"` – while at the same time performing `normalize-space`.

I know that you can find an exact text e.g. by using:

```
//*[normalize-space(text()) = "ABC"]
```

How do I combine these parts?

---

NB: I am using Firefox for Selenium to find elements via `driver.find_element_by_xpath`. As far as I know, Firefox uses XPath 1 and not any later versions of like XPath 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `//*[translate(normalize-space(), 'abc', 'ABC') = 'ABC']` you select elements whose normalized string value is any case version of `ABC`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `or` operator within the XPath expression.
So you can use this locator:

```py
//*[normalize-space(text()) = "ABC" or normalize-space(text()) = "abc"]
```